# Hash Match : Incorrect estimation number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-execution-plan

I have a large table (FactTable) which inner joins to a small table (DimensionTable), so as expected the execution plan is using hash match but for some reason the estimate number of rows on hash match(Inner Join) is 1 record.

I created a copy of DimensionTable table (With all indexes and copy of data ) lets call that table DimensionTable_BKP and used that in the query instead of the actual dimensiontable and the hash match in execution plan for new query is showing correct row estimate

Execution plan for DimensionTable 
[image]

Execution plan for DimensionTable_BKP
[image]

So i tried to run DBCC on DimensionTable and then ran DBCC on index used by the query and they both turned up with no errors

I updated the statistics on that table and that didn't help either

Any other thoughts/suggestions on next steps?

Comment: Are your statistics correct?

Comment: Checked the statistics and it actually sampled all the rows in the table (2000) for the index used and the range in the clustered index looks fine too.

As you can see from the above image, i do not think the DimensionTable is the problem as the estimate rows looks fine (thicker arrows) until it hits the hash match

Comment: dba.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask for this type of question.

Comment: Are statistics' histograms for both pairs of tables are the same? At least you have to post your real query plans.

Comment: Issue solved : Dropped the statistics on that DimensionTable table and recreated the statistics and it worked, probably the statistics were corrupted